# How to search (git grep) changes in specific commit and file type?

Tags: git, grep

I would like to search **all changes** in a specific commit. Note that I want to search only the changes, not the whole changed files.

Here's what I tried:

```
$ git grep -A5 -E -e 'search_term\(.*?,'  <commit_hash>
```

I cannot seem to confine it to just a single commit. The results returned also include search results from files which were not changed in this commit.

How do I limit search to specific file name and type? I can limit to extension but cannot use a pattern as shown below:

```
$ git grep -A5 -E -e 'search_term\(.*?,'  <commit_hash> -- '*.ts
... works
$ git grep -A5 -E -e 'search_term\(.*?,'  <commit_hash> -- 'file_prefix.*\.ts
... does not work!
```

Comment: if you want to search the diffs, why not search the diffs? `git diff thatcommit~ thatcommit -- your path patterns here`.

Comment: @jthill I want to search the context as well, that is, N lines before and M lines after any changes are included in the search. How can I expand how much 'context' is shown in `git diff` output?

Answer (score 1):

Look into

- `git log -G <pattern>` # and its various options
- `git log -S`  # and its various options
- `git show <hash>`
- `git log -p ... | grep`

There are a lot of different ways to do this. With the commands above and `git help <command>` you should be able to find what it is specifically you're looking for.

Comment: Git log doesn't help. Because log only knows changes and not files. I cannot  ask it to fetch 5 lines before a certain search term using `git log ... | grep ...`. If I could use third party tools I wouldn't be using `git grep`.

Comment: Ok, that seems completely contrary to your initial question "I would like to search all changes in a specific commit. Note that I want to search only the changes, not the whole changed files."